# linux semaphore, can a process block itself?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc, semaphore

I use semget() to get a semaphore, and initialize its VAL to 0, then I want to wait it with semop(), but it directly return. (Another process is designed to get the SEM and release it after some operations)

But if I get a SEM and init its VAL to 0 in a process, and wait it in another process, it works.

Does it mean that a process cannot block itself?

thanks!!!

like this:

```
int semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT);
union semun su;
su.val = 0;
semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, su);
struct sembuf sb;
sb.sem_num = 0;
sb.sem_op  = -1;
sb.sem_flg = 0;
semop(semid, &sb, 1);
```

Comment: how do you create the semaphore? can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see at the moment you should:

1. Initialize the semaphore to 1 (su.val)
2. Call semop with sb.sem_op set to 0 (i. e. wait for counter to drop to zero).
3. Drop the count in the other process (sem_op = -1).

Because you initialized the semaphore with 0 and called to decrement it by one (semaphores never go below zero), your wait call will succeed and your process won't block.
Does that help?

Perhaps this may give additional insight:

http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=2

Comment: thanks!! it works!! but I'm still confused why initialize su.val to 0 can block another process. In the other way, how could a process block itself. I'm a newbie in *nix. thanks again for your help, and the web docs.

Comment: This is because if process initializes a semaphore with 0 it enters the critical section at the same time; so others have to wait. If you are wirting green (new) code in your project, maybe you should consider using POSIX semaphores instead (as depicted in the linked article), because the code is a lot easier to maintain (more self-explanatory).